# nodejs make request-promise response available for further processing

Tags: node.js, request-promise

I would like to use request-promise module and do something with response body. However i am not able to make response available outside request-promise scope.

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

rp('http://www.google.com')
    .then(function (response) {
        let variable = response;
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        // rejected
});

console.log(variable); // this will not work right? then, how to make it work in easy way?
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process will work asynchronously so your variable will always be `undefined` or it might throw an error if you declared it inside the async function .

The best approach will be to use `async await`

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
async function getData()
{

let variable=await rp("http://www.google.com");
console.log(variable) // do anything with your variable
}


getData();
```

You would like to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)

Answer (score 0):

3 options for you.

Example 1

```js
const rp = require("request-promise");

rp("http://www.google.com")
  .then(res => {
    // you can use response here
  })
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Example 2

```js
const rp = require("request-promise");

rp("http://www.google.com")
  .then(res => restOfMyCode(res))
  .catch(e => console.log(e));

const restOfMyCode = result => {
  console.log(result);
};
```

Example 3

```js
const rp = require("request-promise");

(async () => {
  try {
    const result = await rp("http://www.google.com");
    console.log(result);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  console.log(result)
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both guys you inspired me to final solution which at the moment looks like this:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

(async () => {

    var data = await getData();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));     


    async function getData() {
            var options = {
                uri: 'https://www.google.com',
                json: true
            };
            var variable=await rp(options);
            return variable; // do anything with your variable
    }

}
) ();
```